# ngbDropDown menu don't match navbar template color

Tags: html, angular, ng-bootstrap

I'm creating a navbar with ngBootstrap and I inserted a login form dropdown.

I created a component to handle this form and the "Perfil" link on the navbar.

The problem is I can't manage the color from the form dropdown, for me it's regardless if I have to use the light or dark theme on the dropdown, but it have to use only one color schema (on this case it is meshing two different ones).

As it's possible see on Image 1 (see below), the links inherit the link color from the navbar, and stays with the same color as the dropdown.

[image]

I tried to change the dropdown theme (with no success) using html code.

On the component.ts I inserted the following on the `styles`:

```
 styles: [`
  background-color: #343a40;
    a:link, a:visited {
  ;
  color: blue;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

And on the `div ngbDropdownMenu` I inserted the following:

`style="background: #343a40;`

The result, as it can be seen below, is that when I mouse hover the button it still uses the light theme

[image]

The full code I used is following:

```
<li class="nav-item dropdown"  ngbDropdown class="d-inline-block" ngbDropdown display="dynamic" placement="bottom-left"> 
  <a class="nav-link dark dropdown-toggle" ngbDropdownToggle id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
    Perfil
  </a>  
    <div ngbDropdownMenu aria-labelledby="dropdownForm1" class="navbar-light" style="background: #343a40; color: white">
    <form class="px-4 py-3">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="exampleDropdownFormEmail1">Email</label>
        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleDropdownFormEmail1" placeholder="email@exemplo.com" autocomplete="username">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="exampleDropdownFormPassword1">Senha</label>
        <input type="password" class="form-control" id="exampleDropdownFormPassword1" placeholder="Senha" autocomplete="current-password">
      </div>
      <div class="form-check">
        <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="dropdownCheck">
        <label class="form-check-label" for="dropdownCheck">
          Lembrar de mim
          <p></p>
        </label>
      </div>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Login <i class = "fas fa-sign-in-alt"></i></button>
    </form>
    <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
    <button ngbDropdownItem>
    <a class="nav-link" [routerLink]= "['register']" routerLinkActive = "active" >
    Novo por aqui? Registre-se</a></button>
    <button ngbDropdownItem>
    <a class="nav-link" [routerLink]= "['reset-password']" routerLinkActive = "active">
    Esqueceu a senha?</a></button>
  </div>
</li>
```

UPDATE: I think the problem may be from the application of ngBootstrap from the original Bootstrap, maybe I will need to include something to handle this.